# unordered_map value type with private constructor

Tags: c++, c++14, unordered-map

I have the need for the following code:

```
class myclass{
    private:
        myclass(){}

        friend myclass *make_myclass(const std::string&);
};

std::unordered_map<std::string, myclass> myclasses;

myclass *make_myclass(const std::string &str){
    if(myclasses.find(str) == myclasses.end())
        myclasses.emplace(str, myclass{});
    return &myclasses[str];
}
```

But compiling this code spews out a very long error about `myclass()` being private.

So I thought I would emplace the `std::pair` and make it a friend:

```
class myclass{
    private:
        myclass(){}

        friend myclass *make_myclass(const std::string&);
        friend class std::pair<std::string, myclass>;
};

std::unordered_map<std::string, myclass> myclasses;

myclass *make_myclass(const std::string &str){
    if(myclasses.find(str) == myclasses.end())
        myclasses.emplace(
            std::piecewise_construct,
            std::forward_as_tuple(str),
            std::forward_as_tuple()
        );
    return &myclasses[str];
}
```

but *still* get the error about the constructor being private.

How can I have a `std::unordered_map` with a type that has a private constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error will be referring to this line:

```
return &myclasses[str];
```

That's because [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) has to default construct a value if it's not there in the map for the particular key. Since that operator isn't a friend of `myclass`, you get the access error.

Instead, you should take advantage of the fact that [`emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace) returns the iterator that it inserted at:

```
myclass *make_myclass(const std::string &str) {
    auto it = myclasses.find(str);
    if (it == myclasses.end()) {
        it = myclasses.emplace(str, myclass{}).first;
    }
    return &it->second;
}
```

This also has the added benefit of not having to do a second lookup on `str`.

Comment: You don't need to test if str exists or not in myclasses. [Emplace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/emplace) won't add str unless it does not exist.

Comment: @Brahim Whether or not that's the right thing to do depends on how expensive `myclass` is to construct.

Comment: @Barry This issue is being addressed in [N 3873 Improved insertion interface for unique-key maps](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3873.html) by adding `emplace_or_update` and `emplace_stable` methods or alternatively in [N4006 An improved emplace() for unique-key maps](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4006.html) by changing `emplace`.

Comment: @IlyaPopov Both irrelevant since it is `make_myclass` that is the one that has to construct the `myclass`. Regardless of how `emplace` and family end up looking, we'd have to pass in `myclass{}`... which could be expensive.

Comment: Indeed, in this particular case it would not help.